# Can the code run from terminal but not from bashscript file

Tags: java, unix, cygwin, sh

When I try to run my code from cygwin terminal, it works fine, however when I try to use the bashscript that I have created, it doesn't work,says "*Error: Unable to access jarfile*" . My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/orhun.vatansever/workspace/extchangegui/src/extchangegui (this is the folder that these files reside in)
java -jar `xyz.jar aegis.xyz`
```

Answer (score 0):

Backquotes are to execute a subshell. Remove them

```
java -jar `xyz.jar aegis.xyz`
```

to

```
java -jar xyz.jar aegis.xyz
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a resource '; a registered resource factory is needed
        at org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResourceSet.getResource(XtextResourceSet.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.resource.SynchronizedXtextResourceSet.getResource(SynchronizedXtextResourceSet.java:26)
        at org.xtext.example.mydsl.generator.Main.runGenerator(Main.java:46)
        at org.xtext.example.mydsl.generator.Main.main(Main.java:28)

Comment: it is supposed to generate a folder src-gen, and it does if I enter this code to terminal manually, but bashscript doesn't seem to be working

Comment: The error you posted "Error: Unable to access jarfile" means java didn't start. This new error, means some runtime resource didn't work correctly (but Java started). You haven't posted any code, but what are you doing at line 28 in Main? Because that is what is throwing this new error.